# Google Chrome - create gmail application shortcut

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, gmail

Since I've started using Chrome I occasionally try to create a Gmail application shortcut - but without success yet. My Chrome version right now is 4.0.249.89 (beta) and OS Windows 7 (Home Premium) - but it didn't work with previous Chrome versions / Windows XP on a different computer either.
The Gmail icon is is not displayed in the shortcut creation dialog and no shortcut is created when clicking 'ok'.

Does everyone on Chrome experience this? Is there a way to fix it?
Application shortcuts for other sites / google web-apps (calendar/docs) work just as expected.

(Please don't post workarounds - I know how to create an application shortcut/icon manually - I'm just curious about this oddity with the built in way to do it)

Comment: I've never had this problem. Strange! Maybe you should file a bug with the Chromium project. +1 on the find.

Answer (score 2):

No problem here, same chrome version / windows 7

look in `C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Plugin Data\Google Gears\mail.google.com\https_443\icons#desktop`

there should be a Gmail.ico and a Gmail_cp.png, maybe are they corrupt?

Comment: Thanks for the hint - that directory exists but is empty.  
The corresponding directory for google calendar (C:\Users\gero\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Plugin Data\Google Gears\www.google.com\https_443\icons#desktop) contains an icon when I create a calendar shortcut (and the icon is also displayed in the create shortcut dialog)..